End of discharge voltage for "refreshing" of NiMH cells
I have been reading some books on NiMH batteries. Some authors state that for optimum performance and longevity NiMH batteries need to be "exercised" or "refreshed" or "reconditioned", that is subject to a complete discharge, followed by a complete charge.
For instance, from the "Ni-MH Technical Handbook" (Panasonic, 2017):

"As with Ni-Cd batteries, repeated charge and discharge of these
batteries under high discharge cut-off voltage conditions (more than
1.1V per cell) causes a drop in the discharge voltage (which is sometimes accompanied by a simultaneous drop in capacity). The
discharge characteristics can be restored by charge and discharge to a
discharge end voltage of down to 1.0V per cell."

This is form the "Handbook of Batteries" (Linden, 2002):

"The voltage drop occurs because only a portion of the active
materials is discharged and recharged during shallow or partial
discharging. The active materials that have not been cycled change in
physical characteristics and increase in resistance. The active
materials are restored to their original state by the subsequent full
discharge-charge cycling."

One author state that such an "exercise" should be done for NiMH batteries at least once every three months.
There is some disagreement as to what "end of discharge voltage" should the cells be discharged to. Some authors suggest 1.0V per cell, others 0.9V per cell. Most authors agree that overdischarge is detrimental to NiMH batteries, but the rationale that they provide is only applicable for cells connected in series: if you discharge several cells connected in series, then because of the capacity mismatch one or more of the cells might get their polarity reversed, if the cut-off voltage is too low. To prevent that from happening people suggest setting the cut-off voltage to 1.0V per cell, or even higher when more cells are connected in series.
Polarity reversal is no doubt detrimental, but it could not happen if cells are discharged individually in a "constant resistance" mode (that is being connected to a load of a "constant" resistance). It is established that for NiCd batteries, discharging to a voltage below 0.9V per cell frequently works better for restoring the battery's performance.
In addition to this I have not found info on how this end of discharge voltage should be measured. By logic it should be the open circuit voltage, but if you look at the discharge plots, it seems as if they measure it with the load connected to the cell.
If you connect a load to a cell, the voltage will keep decreasing, but as soon as you disconnect the load the voltage will start increasing back, not to the original value, but considerably.
Say, I had been discharging a NiMH cell (an AA battery) in a "constant" resistance mode for about 30 hours and the voltage has dropped to 4.8 mV with the load still connected. After I disconnected the load, the cell's voltage started to increase rapidly and in an hour the cell's voltage has risen to 1.1V. Does this mean that the cell was not fully discharged?
So I have these questions:
1) What is the best end of discharge voltage for "refreshing" of a single NiMH cell in a "constant resistance" mode?
2) What is safe end of discharge voltage for discharging of a single NiMH cell in a "constant resistance" mode?
3) Is this an open circuit voltage, or a voltage with the load connected to the cell?
4) If this is an open circuit voltage then how one can practically measure it while discharging a single NiMH cell?

A lot of physical chemistry goes here, but in essence:
The safe end of discharge voltage for a general NiMH cell can be assumed 0.9V for both the general use or the refresh mode. This is what the battery analysers do. This somewhat depends on the discharge current and for very low currents this is lower. E.g. a 2Ah cell discharged at 1mA could be drained safely as low as 0.5V and maybe even less. NiMH chemistry is safe in this regard and it will neither explode nor instantly go bad if drained even down to 0V. SOME of them are even safe at polarity reversal, provided the current is not too high (see the datasheet).
On the other hand, below e.g. 1.0V one only gets very little amount of energy so 1.0V is a good cut-off from the powered device viewpoint.
These are voltages open-circuit, but for moderate discharge rates you can as well measure them under load because the voltage drop in the cell is small and linear-ish. For high currents you may want to use a more complex battery model and to stick to the datasheet in the first place. There, a nice family of discharge curves in different conditions is usually graphed with voltage under load at the axis.

Thank you for your answer. You state that: "a 2Ah cell discharged at 1mA could be drained safely as low as 0.5V". I assume that this statement is based on some tests. Are those tests published somewhere, or you did them yourself and never published them?

Also you state: "NiMH chemistry is safe in this regard and it will neither explode nor instantly go bad if drained even down to 0V". Does this mean that the battery may "slowly go bad" when discharged down to 0V? Because my question is about routine maintenance to prolong battery's longevity and improve it's performance.

@ThomasAnderson the 0.5V figure is somewhat back-of-the-envelope estimation by me, backed by my knowledge of what the failure modes are. In regard to prolonging the battery life, how much exactly is worth the hassle? Off the shelf AA cells do 1000-2000 cycles, industrial cells are even better. And NiMH is more of a niche technology these days anyway.
